# Python library to do path computation without an underlying file system

Tags: python-3.x, path

We have a project with data organized in a hierarchical way that can be seen as folders and files, but inside a database, not a true file system.

I want to write a CLI tool in Python that can do "ls", "cd", "rm", use Tab to autocomplete names.

The CLI tool should not be restricted to absolute paths but should be able to translate glob pattern or relative paths. For that reason, I'm looking for a Python library allowing path computation, something like os.path but that can work even if it is not a true file system.

Comment: Do you mean that [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is also not what you need?

Comment: Actually, pathlib is still tied to a file system but if I can derive my own (Pure)Path implementation that could do the trick. I will investigate this. Thx